# How to iterate a Cold Observable in a cached way

Tags: javascript, set, reactive-programming, rxjs

I wanted to implement the [relative complement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2B4EBvVvf9w) of two finite Observable sequences, and this is the best that I got so far:

```
function relativeComplement (setA, setB, cmp) {

    return setA.concatMap(objA =>
                        setB
                            .reduce((acc, cur) => {
                                if (cmp(objA, cur)) {
                                    return {val: objA, skip:true}
                                }
                                return acc
                            }, {val: objA, skip: false})
                            .filter(obj => !obj.skip)
                            .map(obj => obj.val)
                    )
}
```

The example works but has two issues that I haven't been able to overcome. First, I would like to use scan instead of reduce, because I know that if I already set skip to true, there is no point in continuing the sequence.

The second problem is the one that bothers me the most.

If setB is a cold observable, it will "construct it", or do any side effects it may have attached setA.length number of times.

Here it is a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/nuhuki/edit?js,console) that shows the problem

So I have two questions.

- Do you see another way to implement the relative complement that overcomes this two problems?
- Can I cache the results of setB so it doesn't replay the construction and side effects?

NOTE: Im using RxJs 5 alpha and it doesn't have a replay method in the observable prototype

Comment: For the first problem, I can think of a combination of `expand`, `takeUntil` and `materialize`, but I would wonder if it is really worth it, I mean do you have large B sets for which it would make sense to exit early for the reduce loop?. For the second problem, it seems kind of hard as is. If there is no `replay` operator, you can write your own.

Comment: Yeah, the first problem is not that bad, actually, if the set is really big the whole thing would have to be revisited, and the replay would have no sense. In any case, assuming I have a replay, how would you solve this, figuring out i dont know the size of B

Comment: I believe in RxJS 5 it is called `publishReplay`

Comment: Thanks @paulpdaniels! I'll give it a look, still some code would be welcome as there is no documentation on the subject and I'm fairly new to rx :)

Comment: stupid question : if those are finite observables, why not gather their values into an array, and perform the complement on arrays? Do you need to output the values one by one and as soon as possible?

Comment: @user3743222 your idea is good, I may end up doing that, its probably best in terms of performance and all, but I don't think is a stupid question. And I would still like to know how to "cache" or memoize a cold observable, specially if I don't know its length

Comment: Documentation for `replay`,`shareReplay` here :http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html. Basically `setB.shareReplay()` should be fine in your case. Best is to try. I would recommend you put the `setB.shareReplay()` in a variable before the `return setA.concatMap` though, and reuse that variable inside the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

If you go on the converting the observables in array idea, and supposing you have a function `relativeComplementArray` :

```
function relativeComplement (setA, setB, cmp) {
  return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(setA.toArray(), setB.toArray(), function (arrayA, arrayB){
     return relativeComplementArray(arrayA, arrayB, cmp);
  })
}
```

For a version with `replay` functionality, it is a bit more complicated to use it inside a function, because you need to work not on `setB` but on `setB.shareReplay()`.

I propose you a curried function.

```
function relativeComplement ( setB, cmp ) {
  var sharedSetB = setB.shareReplay();
  return function ( setA ) {
    return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(setA.toArray(), sharedSetB.toArray(), function ( arrayA, arrayB ) {
      return relativeComplementArray(arrayA, arrayB, cmp);
    })
  }
}
```

This is all untested, but hopefully it gets you in the right direction.